# Is there "Java Bean" like technology in PHP?

Tags: php, javabeans

Is there something like the Java Bean stuff in PHP? Thank you.

Comment: Don't think so. But Beans-esque getter/setter methods are used like crazy.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "J2EE Java Bean"? The Java Bean spec is older and completely independent of J2EE (which is actually dead, it*s Java EE now). Or do you in fact mean EJB (Enterprise Java Beans, completely different technology)?

Answer (score 4):

In PHP MVC frameworks such as CakePHP, ZF, Symfony etc...you could say that the equivalent of a JavaBean would be the Model itself (the M) of MVC. A model is where you would have the get / set functionalities that javabeans do. Just FYI, in Symfony, that is called an "entity"

Answer (score 2):

Just going off the info you provided, if by similar to JavaBeans you mean a reusable directory of classes and objects that conform to reasonably unified standards then the closest thing I think would be [PEAR.](http://pear.php.net/)

Answer (score 0):

not by default... but frameworks are something similar because the framework (usually) allows you to to map the POST or GET, build forms and save the info into the db, according to a Model... Like when using beans.. =)

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about red bean php?

Try it and you will experience a great new world.

http://redbeanphp.com/

A great php ORM

Answer (score 0):

java bean is good for managing your resource as it implement the right MVC framework. here are a simple tutorial to implement it on PHP.

https://webdevchoices.wordpress.com/2011/08/21/applying-bean-pattern-in-php-programming/

and here is a snippet for those who are to lazy to click the link

```
class Person {
private $_firstName;
private $_lastName;

public function setFirstName($value) {
    $v = trim($value);
    $this->_firstName = empty($v) ? null : $v;
}

public funtion getFirstName() {
    return $this->_firstName;
}

public function setLasttName($value) {
    $v = trim($value);
    $this->_lastName = empty($v) ? null : $v;
}

public funtion getLastName() {
    return $this->_lastName;
}
```

}